# How do i use a URL to set an setImageBitmap for a ImageView?

Tags: java, android

in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

in the onCreate method:

```
    webImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.webimage); 

   String urlImage = "https://thetab.com/blogs.dir/91/files/2017/01/maxresdefault-1.jpg";

// Set setImageBitmap to Bitmap created by getURLBitmap method
webImage.setImageBitmap(getURLBitmap(urlImage));
```

in the getURLBitmap method:

```
         if(!urlString.isEmpty() || urlString != null) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    // pass the string into a URL object
    try {
        URL urlForImage = new URL(urlString);

        // cast url openConnection into HttpURLConnection
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForImage.openConnection();

        // Set HttpURLConnection setDoInput to true
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        // Start HttpURLConnection connection
        connection.connect();

        if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            // Start reading Http inputStream (getInputStream) and use it to initialize a InputStream object
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            // pass InputStream object into a BitmapFactory's decodeStream (is a static method)
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            // set Bitmap object to decodedStream
            return bitmap;
        }
        // return Bitmap
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    return null;
```

I keep getting this error:

D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.EX.perfectmoment, PID: 26747
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.EX.perfectmoment/com.example.EX.perfectmoment.MemeMainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Your error is `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You should download image in an Async task

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are running a network operation on the UI thread, which is something that is *very* [looked down upon](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#intro) in Android Dev as  it often results in an unresponsive UI and thus, a bad user experience. I recommend either creating your own [ASyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which would do the network operations in another thread and feed it back to the UI thread, or use one of the many popular image libraries there are for Android, such as [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Answer (score 0):

As said in above comment running network task on UI thread in android no longer supported so you have to do UI blocking task on separate thread either using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or some other thread mechanism available.

So by using AsynTask you can do it like mention below code snippet.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ImageView webImage;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        new SetImage().execute();

    }

    private class SetImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{

        final String urlImage = "https://thetab.com/blogs.dir/91/files/2017/01/maxresdefault-1.jpg";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap image = getURLBitmap(urlImage);
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            webImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getURLBitmap(String urlString){
        if(!urlString.isEmpty() || urlString != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            // pass the string into a URL object
            try {
                URL urlForImage = new URL(urlString);

                // cast url openConnection into HttpURLConnection
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForImage.openConnection();

                // Set HttpURLConnection setDoInput to true
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                // Start HttpURLConnection connection
                connection.connect();

                if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    // Start reading Http inputStream (getInputStream) and use it to initialize a InputStream object
                    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    // pass InputStream object into a BitmapFactory's decodeStream (is a static method)
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    // set Bitmap object to decodedStream
                    return bitmap;
                }
                // return Bitmap
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```